# Is it worth learning SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

Is it worth learning MOSS (Microsoft Office SharePoint Server) 2007? What could be the future of it?

Comment: Looks great on CV, You will regret it when your organization implements it!

Answer (score 6):

SharePoint is **the** fastest growing product in Microsoft history.

Even MS can't get enough experienced MOSS developers for support.

Learn MOSS and you should be pretty sure to stay in business, crises and all.

Also it's **fun**. I am aware that it has a rugged reputation when it comes to development, and the lack of good tools can be discouraging for many developers, but the truth is that it's a true ASP.NET application. Especially the deployment can seem cumbersome, but if you do it and do it good, you can move your code from environment to environment without a sweat. I haven't worked with any other CMS products that could do that, and I worked on a few!

So grab a SharePoint book and get coding :-)

Comment: I completely agree with this answer.  Also I have seen my buddies who are SharePoint Architects turn down offers > 150k per year in the current economy.  If you are a good technical leader and are an expert in SharePoint you will have a lot of great opportunities.

Comment: Yeah, "fun", like stabbing yourself in the eye with a pencil :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is if you're working on Microsoft products.

MOSS 2007 is an important part of the office suite of products, and will continue to be, given its gigantic uptake and excellent revenue stream for Microsoft.

The next release of MOSS is due in 2010, and I imagine the integration with Microsoft Office and other products will increase, and also become more transparent.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint and MOSS is a great niche market to be in.  It looks great on resumes and is in pretty heavy demand in the job market.

Answer (score 0):

It's hot, and not many people completely understand it, but every big company wants it... Join us on the bandwagon!

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint is kind of notice board in the organisation. If its there in an organization, it helps to store various documents and publish news etc. But it is one of the product where you cannot have easy control on it. Its only content management systems but cannot be very flexible for realtime applications development.Sharepoint designer is one of the worst thing which generates ugly html tags. Its waste of time in learning SharePoint. Let me tell you a simple example: Refer the follwoing post.

To perform a simple thing you need to do hacky and cheap kind of tricks:

[Click Here for small example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32045/display-list-item-when-a-field-is-not-empty)

If I were you I would never go for it! Because microsoft is already in to it, they are marketing heavily, but its not very good.

MVC is clean and neat, you can develop robust appliactions with it.